# How to multiply a 3-Dimensional Array in Python by 1-Dimensional Array in The Third Dimension

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

New to Python (python 3), I have been struggling with what I feel should be an incredibly simple operation. I have a 3D array of ones, dimensions are:

`3d_array =(1, 65436, 8)`

I have a set of 8 values, which I create a 1-D array using:
`force_type_3d = np.array([7206, 7207, 7208, 7211, 7212, 7213, 7214, 7215])`

I want to multiply the third dimension of the 3-D array by these values, so that each value along dimension two is identical for each row of dimension 3. I thought this would be simple, but Python array multiplication seems extremely counter-intuitive to me. Thanks.

Comment: Using broadcast rules makes this easy: array_3d*force_type_3d.reshape(1, 1, 8).  numpy will broadcast automatically for you, and this results in no copies being made, which can be important if memory is an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.multiply`:

```
ono = np.ones((2,2,8))
ono

array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

       [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])

np.multiply(ono,force_type_3d)

array([[[7206., 7207., 7208., 7211., 7212., 7213., 7214., 7215.],
        [7206., 7207., 7208., 7211., 7212., 7213., 7214., 7215.]],

       [[7206., 7207., 7208., 7211., 7212., 7213., 7214., 7215.],
        [7206., 7207., 7208., 7211., 7212., 7213., 7214., 7215.]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

We all have studied "Sets" during our school-age in Mathematics. Just consider 3D numpy array as the formation of "sets".

```
x = np.zeros((1, 65436, 8)) #or
x = np.ones((1, 65436, 8),dtype=np.int16)
```

The function zeros creates an array full of zeros, the function ones creates an array full of ones.By default, the dtype of the created array is float64.

**Means:**

```
1 Sets, 65436 Rows per Set, 8 Columns
```

then you can use:

```
result =np.multiply(x1, x2) #or
result = x1*x2
```